# implement Gaussian distribution with singular sigma

Tags: algorithm, gaussian

I am implementing the Gaussian distribution model on some data, if the sigma(covariance matrix) is singular, then it's not invertible, and will result in the failure in calculating the probability. I think add an Identity matrix to the sigma will make the sigma invertible, but that will make the model not fits the data.

Is there a way to make the sigma matrix invertible and keep the model fitting data?

Have a set of data: (x1, x2)_1 , (x1, x2)_2 , ... , (x1, x2)_i . where x1 and x2 are continues real numbers and some (x1, x2) can appear serval times, And I assumpt that those data follow Guassian distribution, and then can calculate the mean vector as (mean(x1), mean(x2)), and then calculate the covariance matrix as usual.  And in some case the covariance matrix may be singular, I think add some random small shifts to it can make it nonsingular, but I don't know how to do it correctly so that the model can still fit data well.

Comment: Where did you get this covariance matrix from? Can you include it in your post? I know that in the case of 2 random variables, a singular correlation matrix means one random variable is a deterministic function of the other and so one of them is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to model one dimension of the data with a 1D gaussian distribution in this case.

If you have two-dimensional data `{(x1,x2)_i}` whose covariance matrix is singular, this means that the data lies along a straight line. The `{x2}` data is a deterministic function of the `{x1}` data, so you only need to model the `{x1}` data randomly. The `{x2}` data follows immediately from `{x1}` and is no longer random once you know `{x1}`.

Here is my reasoning:

The covariance matrix would look something like this, since all covariance matrices are symmetric:

```
| a  b |
| b  c |
```

Where `a = var(x1)`, `c = var(x2)`, `b = cov(x1,x2)`.

Now if this matrix is singular, the second column vector would have to be a scalar multiple of the first (since they are linearly dependent). Let's say the constant is `k`. Then:

```
b = k*c
a = k*b = k*k*c
```

So the covariance matrix really looks like:

```
| k*k*c  k*c |
|  k*c    c  |
```

Here there is only one parameter `c = var(x2)` which determines the distribution (since `k` can be anything), so the data in inherently one-dimension. Modelling it with one variable `x1` is enough. Another way of seeing this is by checking that the [Pearson Correlation Coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) for this distribution is `b/(sqrt(a)*sqrt(c)) = 1`.

Comment: but those data are sampled from real world, it can be viewed as object's location. So for every object, I collect its location records, and train 2D Gaussian model on every single object. And most object's covariance matrix is invertible. Maybe the sampling is insufficient, a small set of the objects have only a few records or the records accidentally appear in a line or even a single place.

Comment: I'd suggest plotting the data of the objects that give you a singular covariance matrix, maybe in MATLAB if you are familiar with it. I expect they will be travelling in a straight line. There isn't any other path that would create a singular covariance matrix. With those objects you can either use a 1D model or try to gather more data.

Comment: but no more data is available, and I hope to model every objects in a 2D model, not only because it's more neat, but also in reality no objects will always travel in a straight line. So under this circumstance, if I get a covariance matrix as [1000 2000; 2000 4000], is it a good idea to randomly shift it to [1000.2834 1999.9948; 1999.8472 3999.299]? Or will it cause some weird things?

Comment: I'd say that's a good idea if you are sure you want to use 2D gaussians. You will end up with a very "skinny" 2D gaussian distribution which is very close to a straight line. You must keep in mind that the matrix should be **symmetric**, since `sigma(1,2) = sigma(2,1) = cov(X1,X2)` are always equal in a covariance matrix. Make sure you change these entries by the same amount.